# Reading Values from a Bag of Tuples in pig

Tags: tuples, apache-pig

I have UDF output as :-

> Sample records:-
>   ({(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,5),(Todd,10),(Todd,20),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10)})
>
> ({(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,5),(Jon,10),(Jon,20),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,5),(Jon,20),(Jon,1)})

Schema for UDF:- name:chararray(1 single column)

Now i want to read this bag of tuples and generate output as :-

```
Todd,240
Jon,422
```

The output of the UDF i stored in a temp file and read it back using different schema as:-

```
D = LOAD '/home/training/pig/pig/UDFdata.txt' AS (B: bag {T: tuple(name:chararray, denom:int)});
```

After that i am trying to use foreach loop and reference dot notation to find the sum.

```
X = foreach D generate B.T.name,SUM(B.T.denom);
```

> 2017-03-04 13:52:59,507 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt: ERROR
>   1128: Cannot find field T in name:chararray,denom:int Details at
>   logfile: /home/training/pig_1488648405070.log

Can you please let me know how to find it? I am new to Apache Pig so not sure how it traverse in Bag of Tuples and find sum.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP the dataset on name before performing SUM.

`FLATTEN` the bag to perform `GROUP`.

```
flattened = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(B);

dump flattened;
...
(Todd,10)
(Todd,10)
(Jon,1)
(Jon,1)
....
```

Then, `GROUP` them on `name`

```
grouped = GROUP flattened by name;

dump grouped;
(Jon,{(Jon,1),(Jon,20),(Jon,5),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,10),(Jon,20),(Jon,10),(Jon,5),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1),(Jon,1)})
(Todd,{(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,10),(Todd,20),(Todd,10),(Todd,5),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1),(Todd,1)})
```

And apply `SUM()` over the result

```
final_sum = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group, SUM(flattened.denom);

dump final_sum;
(Jon,106)
(Todd,100)
```